# react: how to persist component specific data

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react ecosystem and wonder where to store the data that would only be initialized once in component's `constructor` based on the props.
I don't think state is a good answer as I thought the state should store data would change.
And moving the `basedOn` function outside this component seems moving the component's inner logic elsewhere.
Does it make sense to bind those data directly to `this`?

```
class example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //where to store this constVar that initialized once base on the this.props 
    const constVar = basedOn(props)
  }
  render() {
    //how to get the constVar?
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use the class context, with `thisthis.constVar`.

Comment: @daniloprates, thanks for the quick response. Do you have any articles for this? Or is this solution come from your practise and experience?

Comment: daniloprates is right that you could simply store the data as `this.constVar = basedOn(props)`, but that somewhat defeats the point of the props: If you're going to do that, you should also implement a `componentWillReceiveProps()` method that handles whatever happens when the props you based `constVar` on really _do_ change. Either way, this kind of caching is a micro-optimization that should really only be done if `basedOn()` comes up hot in profiling; 99 times out of 100, caching the computation isn't actually a performance win.